# UIRotationGestureRecognizer - rotate about anchor point

Tags: ios, uiview, uigesturerecognizer, gesture-recognition

Here is my current implementation of the gesture recognizer:

```
- (IBAction)handleRotate:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

if([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

    _lastRotation = 0.0;
    return;
}

CGFloat rotation = 0.0 - (_lastRotation - [recognizer rotation]);

CGAffineTransform currentTransform = self.container.transform;
CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(currentTransform,rotation);

[self.container setTransform:newTransform];

_lastRotation = [recognizer rotation];

}
```

Works fine. The problem is that self.container always rotates around it's center. I'd like it to rotate around the midpoint of the two touches, so that if you're zoomed in you can just rotate around the area you're touching. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure if you can set a point to outside of the bounds of the object being rotated, but your containers layer property will allow you to specify an anchor point from the transform.

It accepts values from 0.0-1.0 top left to bottom right.

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

[[container layer] setAnchorPoint:myCGPoint];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can place the center point to any `CGPoint` type variable using the code

```
recognizer.view.center = CGPoint(x,y);
```

For more explanation you can refer [this](https://github.com/AalokParikh/pinch-and-uiguesture) example

**(In the pangesturerecognizer handeling method it shows how to set center for view)**

Happy Coding :)

**EDIT 1**

Ok I got the code for how to get the touch locations in view (any) for that first required thing is to enable multipal touch property for the view. (see the below picture)

[image: multipal touch enabled in XIB]

Then implement the delegate method as follow

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"Began %@",touches);
    NSUInteger touchCount = 0;
    for(UITouch *tu in touches)
    {
        CGPoint pt = [tu locationInView:self.view];
        NSLog(@"pt %f, %f",pt.x,pt.y);
        touchCount ++;
    }
    NSLog(@"touchCount %d",touchCount);
}
```

This method shows the touches in `NSLog`. I use `self.view` just for demonstration you can use any view.

Modify this method according to your requirement and get the center point using the two points' coordinates using the calculations as below

p3.x = (p1.x + p2.x)/2;
p3.y = (p1.y + p2.y)/2;

Here p1,p2 are two touch points you got in above mentioned delegate method and the p3 is the center point you required.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: I tried your code but get this: No visible @interface for 'UIRotationGesture' declares the selector 'translationInView'. I need to know how to find the center of a UIRotationGesture.

Comment: you have to get the current touch points location in two CGPoints as for rotation there must be minimum two touch count is required using that points find the mid point and assign that point as center of view using the above code :)

Comment: `touchesBegan:withEvent:` use this delegate to get two touches stored as two touch points and use them in your `handleRotate:` method :) for more explanation see [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIGestureRecognizer/touchesBegan:withEvent:)

Comment: I've been struggling with this for many hours. Given my code above could you possibly show how I could use the methods you describe to find the center point of the two touches and rotate around that point?

Comment: Ok just wait for some time, until I'm posting the answer here :)

Comment: So please refer the edit 1 part of my answer for finding the center point between two touches :) use [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Touches/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007435) reference for more under standing and do some more thing with touches :)

Comment: ?? @soleil what? does this is helpful to you ?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I can implement touchesBegan, and it logs the touch points. It's still not clear how to correlate those results with the code I have posted above though.